# how to delete the first and third column from a text file in python

Tags: python

So I want to delete the first and third column of this text file my text file Looks like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

And I want to delete the first column and third column with python.

My Code Looks like this:

```
f = open("5.txt", "r")
g = open("datafile_fixed.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write("\t".join(line.split()[1:]) + "\n")

f.close()
g.close()
```

but I can only delete the first column. How do I delete the first and third?

Comment: Don't vandalise your own questions once you've received an answer.

Comment: Don't vandalise your own questions once you received an answer and someone reverted your vandalized question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
g.write("\t".join(line.split()[1:-1]) + "\n")
```

Comment: OMG Thank You very much you are the best

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: I will in 11 minutes